# PyTorch Runtime error while running on cuda

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I am trying to run inference on data on GPU. The code works fine on CPU but fails on GPU with the error:

```
RuntimeError: Tensor for 'out' is on CPU, Tensor for argument #1 'self' is on CPU, 
but expected them to be on GPU (while checking arguments for addmm)
```

Here is the model definition:

```
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        # encoder
        self.enc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=672, out_features=256)
        self.enc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=128)
        self.enc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=64)
        self.enc4 = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=32)
        self.enc5 = nn.Linear(in_features=32, out_features=16)

        self.enc1 = nn.ModuleList([self.enc1])
        self.enc2 = nn.ModuleList([self.enc2])
        self.enc3 = nn.ModuleList([self.enc3])
        self.enc4 = nn.ModuleList([self.enc4])
        self.enc5 = nn.ModuleList([self.enc5])

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.enc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.enc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.enc3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.enc4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.enc5(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec5(x))
        return x
```

The place where I use it:

```
def get_device():
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        device = 'cuda:0'
    else:
        device = 'cpu'
    return device    

def test_image_reconstruction(net, testloader):
    final_output = []
    for batch in testloader:
        img, label = batch
        img = img.to(device)
        net = net.to(device)
        outputs = net(img)
        loss = criterion(outputs, img)
    
    return final_output

df = pd.read_parquet(data_path)

net = torch.load(model_path)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
device = get_device()

final_output = test_image_reconstruction(net, valloader)
```

Looks like the error is coming from outputs = net(img) part. Do you know how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your network parameters are at CPU, move it to GPU:

```py
net = net.to(device)
```